# How To Change Value for input on parents jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two *input* inside same *div* and need to change the *value* of one when I write in another one:
Note: I need to use `this` because I have same div with same *class* and *id*.

**My Code:**

```js
function customInput() {
  let customContent = event.target.value;
  let customInput = this.parents('.1');

  $(customInput .a1 .b1).val(customContent);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
    <div class="a1">
        <input type="text" class="b1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="a2">
        <input type="text" class="b2" value="" onkeyup="customInput()">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="1">
    <div class="a1">
        <input type="text" class="b1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="a2">
        <input type="text" class="b2" value="" onkeyup="customInput()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as I can understand you right, the requirement is: The values from both input fields -with class .b1- are always synchronised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer the current element in the function you can pass `this` to the function.

You can try with [**`.closest()`**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [**`.find()`**](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```js
function customInput(el) {
  $(el).closest('.1').find('.b1').val(el.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
    <div class="a1">
        <input type="text" class="b1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="a2">
        <input type="text" class="b2" value="" onkeyup="customInput(this)">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="1">
    <div class="a1">
        <input type="text" class="b1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="a2">
        <input type="text" class="b2" value="" onkeyup="customInput(this)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Though I prefer using [**`.on()`**](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach the event (not using the inline event handler) along with *input* event:

```js
$('.b2').on('input', function() {
  $(this).closest('.1').find('.b1').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
    <div class="a1">
        <input type="text" class="b1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="a2">
        <input type="text" class="b2" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="1">
    <div class="a1">
        <input type="text" class="b1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="a2">
        <input type="text" class="b2" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are kinda mixing plain javascript with jQuery. Altough this works fine, I think it's better to stick to one as much as possible for readability so I changed all your code to jQuery.

Instead of inline event binding I used jQuery event binding. I recommend to avoid inline binding because it easier to maintain and you can bind multiple handlers to one event or toggle them with the jQuery `off()` method.

Also changed the `keyup` event to an `input` event because that also works on for example copy pasting, you could stick to the keyup event if you don't want that of course.

With the jQuery `closest()` function you can find the first matching parent.
With the jQuery `find()` function you can find the matching children.

You can beautify your code a bit to use jQuery chaining if you like. So my commented one liner.

With the find function you can find elements within the parent.

```js
$('.b2').on('input', function() {
    let $this = $(this);
    let customContent = $this.val();
    let $customInput = $this.closest('.1');

    $($customInput).find('.a1 .b1').val(customContent);

    //One liner that does the same.
    //$(this).closest('.1').find('.b1').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
    <div class="a1">
        <input type="text" class="b1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="a2">
        <input type="text" class="b2" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="1">
    <div class="a1">
        <input type="text" class="b1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="a2">
        <input type="text" class="b2" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```